# What is the standard code to check for valid/existing id in database-backed view in web2py?

Tags: error-handling, web2py, http-error

In web2py, suppose I have the following url:

`www.example.com/customer/view/1`

Which is backed by a `view()` function in the `customer` controller and displays the customer with id of 1 from a database.

In the `view` function I want to handle the following error cases:

1. No argument is passed (`/customer/view/`) -> raise 404
2. A non-integer argument is passed (`/customer/view/apple`) -> raise 404
3. An integer argument is passed but does not exist in database (`/customer/view/999999`) -> raise 404
4. An application error occurs such as cannot connect to database -> raise 500 exception

What is the standard/canonical/correct way to handle these cases in the controller function in way that returns the proper HTTP error?  It's such a common scenario that I'd like to do it in a correct and succinct way every time.

This almost works except it doesn't distinguish between id not valid/existing errors and any other errors:

```
def view():
    try:
        customer = db(db.customer.id==request.args(0, cast=int)).select()[0]
    except:
        raise HTTP(404, 'Cannot find that customer')

    return dict(customer=customer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def view():
    id = request.args(0, cast=int, otherwise=lambda: None)
    customer = db(db.customer.id == id).select().first()
    if not customer:
        raise HTTP(404, 'Cannot find that customer' if id
                   else 'Missing/invalid customer ID')
    return dict(customer=customer)
```

If the cast fails in request.args(), by default it will raise its own HTTP(404), but you won't have control over the message. So, you can instead use the `otherwise` argument to return `None` in that case. The database query will then return `None` if the arg is missing or a non-integer, or if the customer is not found in the database.